# Updating the version info of a CHM file during compile with Inno

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to **add version info** to a **CHM** file whilst **compiling** the a **setup** executable?

Here is a bit of history about my application. In the past I always installed the CHM file with the setup:

```
[Files]
Source: "CommunityTalks.chm"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

Beginning with my next version I am going to have my help documentation **online**. However, I am going to put the CHM version of the file on my site. The user can then opt to download and use this local CHM file instead of going online.

So, there are a couple of things I am trying to achieve:

1. When they install this new version I would like it to check for the presence of the CommunityTalks.chm file in the app folder. If it does not have any version information it should be deleted.
2. When I am compiling the setup I want to add version information to my external CHM file so that I know I can just upload it to the website afterwards.

This way, when a user chooses to download the CHM I will be able to check the version that they have.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Sorry for the confusion. That was an error on my part. I have reworded the question with more background info.

Comment: 1) So does chm have version info? Or are you asking that as well? (I do not know if chm has version info). 2) If it does have version info, do you have a command-line tool or any other "automatable" way to update version info?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl 1) Alas, right-clicking the CHM in File Explorer I can't see anywhere to display version information. :(

Comment: See [Add and get CHM file version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25721534/850848) - 
 *".chm files don't have version information"*

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks. Pity that answer did not show how to read a topic from the file.